# How can I combine this INSERT and SELECT MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

This pulls back one row:

```
SELECT id FROM pin WHERE pinpicsid = '1'
```

I need the result of that statement to go where this X is:

```
INSERT INTO user_collection (pinid, username)
VALUES (X, 'ethanwa')
```

Is there a way to combine these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the INSERT INTO SELECT -statement

```
INSERT INTO user_collection (pinid, username)
SELECT id, 'ethanwa' FROM pin WHERE pinpicsid = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO user_collection (pinid, username)
SELECT id, 'ethanwa' 
FROM pin 
WHERE pinpicsid = '1'
```