# How Can I Combine a SELECT Statement that Returns Multiple Rows with an INSERT Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

This returns **multiple** rows:

`SELECT field_one FROM table_one WHERE field_two = value_three`

I need the results of that statement to go where `value_one` is in this one:

`INSERT INTO table_one (field_one, field_two) VALUES(value_one, value_two)`

My question is similar to this one ([How can I combine this INSERT and SELECT MySQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20337409/2097294)) except that my SELECT statement will return **multiple** rows.

Comment: doesn't matter how many rows - they all will get inserted with the INSERT ... SELECT syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_one (field_one, field_two) 
SELECT field_one, value_two
FROM table_one
WHERE field_two = value_three
```